# Setting FNR value in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

Is there any way you can alter the default value of FNR and then output it to the screen.

I have tried:

```
(piped output....) | awk '{FNR=0} {print $0, FNR}'
```

I am hoping that solution will be interhangeable with NR.

Comment: What do you mean by the default value? `FNR` is the number of the current input record so it changes per record.

Comment: I believe you can set FNR to any number so you can start at 0 or 2 and then increment from there.

Comment: record numbers are not 0-based but 1-based. FNR==1 is the first line

Comment: Is there any way, to set this to start from another number such as 2 or 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, by using `BEGIN`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FNR=2} {print $0, FNR}' file.txt
one 3
two 4
three 5
four 6
```

However, this seems not to work when input is not `stdin` (i.e. a file argument is given; at least not in GNU awk).

Comment: Absolute star, it is amazing you are able to manipulate the values of FNR so easily.

Answer (score 2):

Why not declare your own `offset` variable:

```
(piped output....) |  awk 'BEGIN {offset=2} {print $0, FNR+offset}'
```

Comment: You might want that declaration in the `BEGIN` clause so it's not unnecessarily executed for each line of input. Otherwise +1.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is: DO NOT DO THAT!!!! Leave FNR alone, it is what it is. If you need some counter that represents something other than the number of records read so far in the current file, then simply create a counter to represent that, don't go messing with the meaning of the built-in variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'FNR > 2 {print $0, FNR}' yourfilename
```

FNR isn't necessarily interchangeable with NR. If you specify multiple files, FNR reinitializes to zero before each file. NR doesn't.